# ts-node --version runs incredibly long

Tags: ts-node

The execution time of a simple `ts-node --version` needs a long time

I have a fresh virtual maschine (xen, 20GB RAM, lots of free space) with ubuntu 18.04 server. node/npm installed via package manager. Unfortunately the execution of a simple ts-node --version needs really long time to finish:

```
time ./node_modules/.bin/ts-node --version
ts-node v7.0.1
node v8.10.0
typescript v3.6.4
cache "/tmp/ts-node-94a6b447580330f9f2b609422537b04239ff3a39df9137e32efd559f1a2935cb/9d1b7d973ebcaeec54cd97f2de9eb4549430f03609c30b1504d897556bb2d5af"

real    2m44,511s
user    0m32,442s
sys     0m19,245s
```

Using a local virtual maschine (ubuntu 18.04 but virtual box and only 6GB RAM) the same request needs under a second:

```
time ./node_modules/.bin/ts-node --version
ts-node v7.0.1
node v8.10.0
typescript v3.6.4
cache "/tmp/ts-node-1da900a950c0ee3f0f80ae0bb561a80b80e89de692835d79984eb12d0a2f2a44/ca51062b04b699dcb91ec472983c8d598ee9fb43791553c229cba71256858f5a"

real    0m0,918s
user    0m0,840s
sys     0m0,083s
```

`./node_modules/.bin/ts-node --help`  is really fast.

If I look in `./node_modules/.bin/ts-node` (link to `../ts-node/dist/bin.js`) the following prodecure is the problem:

```
var service = index_1.register({
    files: argv.files,
    pretty: argv.pretty,
    typeCheck: argv.typeCheck,
    transpileOnly: argv.transpileOnly,
    cache: argv.cache,
    cacheDirectory: argv.cacheDirectory,
    ignore: argv.ignore,
    project: argv.project,
    skipIgnore: argv.skipIgnore,
    skipProject: argv.skipProject,
    compiler: argv.compiler,
    ignoreDiagnostics: argv.ignoreDiagnostics,
    compilerOptions: index_1.parse(argv.compilerOptions) || index_1.DEFAULTS.com
pilerOptions,
    readFile: isEval ? readFileEval : undefined,
    fileExists: isEval ? fileExistsEval : undefined
});
```

I use following tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

fresh `npm install`

Versions:

```
node --version
v8.10.0

npm --version
3.5.2
```

Maybe someone has an idea...

Answer (score 0):

just found the reason for this strange behaviour:
the project-directory included a link to a huge image-directory with 100k+ image-files. If I remove the link, everything works as expected.

Thanks!